# Returning value above and below column range

Tags: excel, indexing, range, match, cell

I have a list of countries (B column) ordered by Rank (A column) in a Pivot Table. I have a drop down data validation list to select any one of these countries.

Once a country is selected I wish to automatically show the 5 countries below and 5 countries above the selected.

The A and B ranges go +5 and -5 above and below to try and return blanks if there is no country higher or lower than selected. I am currently using this formula for example;

```
 =INDEX(A:B,MATCH(Selected_Country,B,0)+1,COLUMN(B))
```

In particular this formula returns the next lowest country down the list as it is "+1" from the matched selected country. The "+1" can then be changed to "-1" and so on to show lower or higher countries in column B.

As this is set up to read from a Pivot Table, the column heading "Countries" and a few report filter headings are +5 above the highest country in the list and blank rows cannot be inserted to show blanks due to it being a Pivot Table.

This means that when I select the highest country in the list, it shows "Countries" as the next highest and so on. An IF statement based on the text e.g -IF "Countries" return blank- would have to also include all report filter titles and becomes messy.

Is there any other way to apply an IF statement which could omit these headings, maybe based on cell format?

Comment: Use the aggregate function. There are lots of examples of this site.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I will have a look around see if I can make it work.

Comment: I am having difficulty making it work in my favour. Could you provide an example of how you would do this please? My formula is curently =IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$C$22,MATCH(J3,$B$3:$B$22,0)-1,COLUMN($B‌​$3:$B$22)),"") not sure where and what options to use with aggregate function in order to return "blank" when indexed value is outside a given range (i.e the list of countries B3:B22)

Comment: I don't retype data from images and I've all but given up trying to impress on people that asking multiple viewers of a question to each retype blocks of data is just a [lazy-ass way of posting a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557). If you cannot provide a [mcve] then I will wish you good luck on your project and move on. There are plenty of well-crafted questions that do not require me to retype data in order to proof a response.

Comment: Apologies, new to forums in general let alone SO. I have edited to try and simplify let me know if this is still too complicated and wordy.

Comment: See an example worksheet I prepared yesterday [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Issues%20returning%20value%20above%20and%20below%20column%20range.xlsb). It relies more on the ranking than the country name but that is easily reversible.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this formula. I think you are seeking something like this only.

Enter this formula in "G5". arrange data as shown in image.

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($B$2:$B$51,MATCH($G$3,$B$2:$B$51,0),0))),$F5,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question and sorry its taken so long to reply. Aditya, that does appear very similar to the setup i currently have, the main issue I am trying to solve is that when you select a country, for example "Indonesia" where the 5 countries above would be 1 united States, 2 India, 3 China, 4 Country, 5 Blank. I need these to show as blank if they are not a country.

Comment: Just include IFERROR to get the result.   =IFERROR(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($B$2:$B$51,MATCH($G$3,$B$2:$B$51,0),0))),$F5,0),"")

Comment: I did try IFERROR, there seemed to be an issue possibly due to the data being in a Pivot Table (necessary to make it automated) where it would return a random country from the list where it should have returned "Country" if "China" was selected. I have now solved this by ensuring there are +5 blank cells above "China" and below lowest on the list so it just INDEX's these blank cells. I had to input a space for the "Country" heading and for report filter headings above this cell from from the Pivot Table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help anyways, much appreciated :)